# Length of regex expression with specific values

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript regex against a text area in an html form.  Here's the regex:

```
    regex = /[EePp]+/
```

I would like to also use the regex to check the length of the string in the text area and to have it to be limited to a single character.

I tried

```
    regex = /[EePp]{1}/
```

And it validates regex to only those characters, but still allows strings of more than one character in the text area:

```
    <input type='text' onkeypress='validate(event)'>
```

Is it possible to do that through the regex?

Comment: why not `['p', 'e'].indexOf(form.field.value.toLower())` or something similar? regex just to enforce a single char in a case insensitive manner is like using a bazooka to swat a fly.

Comment: I actually resolved it by having onkeypress='return ( this.value.length < 1 );'

Comment: that won't check for E/P though, just that your field is 0 chars.

Comment: Tim, in that case you can post an answer to your own question.  Further, you can, after some time, accept the answer to your own question.  This is considered a good practice on Stack Oveflow, because it makes the helpful result clear to future readers of the question!

Comment: I actually had an account like that a while back, but I'm not sure how I logged into it, or what username it was. In any case, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

If you add anchors, `^` and `$` at the start and end of your regex, this will limit it to matching only the pattern and nothing else against the full extent of what is being searched.

So, `/^[EePp]{1}$/`  -- That says [EePP] at the very beginning of what is being searched,`^`, and there is nothing between it and the end, `$`, of what is being searched.

Turns out that in this case you don't need the `{1}`, because the anchors are telling it exactly how far the match extends.  So:

`/^[EePp]$/`

should do it.

Comment: This is good explanation. To simplify further you could just use `/^[ep]$/i` for case-insensitive search.

Comment: Thank you for your info. Hmm, I actually think this is a javascript error, since I only grab each key separately and it then will be a 1 char string.

Comment: @MikeBrant: No, I think it needs to remain a chracter class.  Either an e or p.  So your modification could look like this, I think. `/^[ep]$/i`.  But you're right that the /i flag can help here.

Comment: @DWright Yes it does.  I left that out (was just trying to show use of `i` pattern modifier. :)

Comment: @Tim, I don't think I followed what you said about a javascript error.

Comment: The problem was that javacript check was run on each key press       `key = String.fromCharCode( key );` so it would grab that and run regex check on it instead of the field contents, so it would always be a string with length of one, but the actual field would contain more characters.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Make sure you post this and info about `return ( this.value.length < 1)` as an actual answer, not just a comment.  However, you'll want to absorb the other comments, such as @MarcB above, just to be sure you've  covered everything.